# Gnu make: Target in macro from subst

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to generate a list of equivalent targets:

```
TARGETLIST = a b c d e f 

define RULE
$(subst X,$(1),file_X.txt) $(subst X,$(1),otherfile_X.txt) &: # some dependency
    # some commands
endef

$(foreach _t, $(TARGETLIST), $(eval $(call RULE, $(_t))))
```

This does not do what I want: If I want to build `file_b.txt` for example the recipe is not found. How do I fix this?

Comment: what do the dependencies look like and any relation the example elements `a b c ...` ?

Comment: @Milag That does not seem to matter. It does not work for no dependencies.

Comment: a `patsubst` could easily generate `file_a.txt file_b.txt ...` from the initial list, the result assigned to another var, and use that var leading a target rule; details of dependencies could vary the design

Comment: @Milag That does not work; I left some part out of my answer. See the updte. Each `file_X.dat` is grouped with another `otherfile_X.dat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from the double expansion that takes place in your macro when calling `foreach-eval-call`. You need to double the `$` of your `$(subst...`: `$$(subst...`. But why not simply letting `call` do your substitutions?

```
TARGETLIST = a b c d e f 

define RULE
file_$(1).txt otherfile_$(1).txt &: # some dependency
    # some commands
endef
$(foreach _t,$(TARGETLIST),$(eval $(call RULE,$(_t))))
```

`call` automatically replaces the `$(1)` occurrences in the `RULE` macro by the current `$(_t)` of the `foreach` loop. This is what `call` is made for.